# Why do I get Inconsistent Accessibility error?

Tags: c#

I'm sorry I'm new to C# and WPF.

```
namespace MyProgram
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of TSearchFiles.
    /// </summary>
    public class TSearchFiles
    {
        private TBoolWrapper canceled;

        public TSearchFiles(TBoolWrapper bw)
        {
            canceled = bw;
        }

        public List<TPhotoRecord> GetFilesRecursive(string b)
        {

            List<TPhotoRecord> result = new List<TPhotoRecord>();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error message:

```
Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProgram.TPhotoRecord>' is less accessible than method 'MyProgram.TSearchFiles.GetFilesRecursive(string)'
```

How to fix it?  The code compiled fine in Winforms

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably `TPhotoRecord` class is `private`, i.e.

```
private class TPhotoRecord
{
    //...
}
```

As far as you return a `List<TPhotoRecord>` in a public method of a public class:

```
public class TSearchFiles
{
    //...
    public List<TPhotoRecord> GetFilesRecursive(string b){/*...*/}
}
```

`TPhotoRecord` cannot be less accessible, i.e. it also should be `public.`

Answer (score 2):

Your `class TPhotoRecord` should be public because the method `public List<TPhotoRecord> GetFilesRecursive(string b)` is public.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TPhotoRecord` class is private, so you can't talk about it in a return type of a public method.