# Inconsistent Accessibility Error in c# can't call base

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, layout

I am creating an application with a lot of forms and the visual style required takes a lot time to be applied from the designer, so I created a class called Layout to apply these
property changes to every form on its Load() method.

```
      class Layout : Form
    {
        public void ApplicarLayout(Form frm)
        {
            frm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(30)))), ((int)(((byte)(30)))), ((int)(((byte)(30)))));
            foreach (Control c in frm.Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    //Apply textBox Formatting
                }
                //Iterate through the controls in the form and add respective format
            }
        }
    }
```

So far, so good. My plan was to then inherit this class from every form and just call the base.AplicarLayout() method.However, I get the error:

```
Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'EntityClub_.Layout' is less accessible than class 'EntityClub_.MainAdminWindow'
```

Here you can see how I do it.

```
    public partial class MainAdminWindow : Layout
{
    public MainAdminWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void MainAdminWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.ApplicarLayout(this);//ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

Do you know how can I do this using inheritance? I don't want to instance the class and I don't want to pollute each window´s code with the layout method.

Comment: `public class Layout`... Layout needs to be public also (they are private by default).

Comment: A guess: Layout is internal isn't it? change it to public.

Comment: class is implied `private` if you don't explicitly declare it `public class your class`

Comment: @SimonWhitehead thank you, that solved the problem. Post it as an answer so I can choose it as the solution. (You answered first) Thanks a lot.

Comment: please see [C# Inconsistent Accessibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249963/wpf-c-sharp-inconsistent-accessibility/14249981#14249981)

Comment: BTW `System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(30)))), ((int)(((byte)(30)))), ((int)(((byte)(30)))));` why so many parentheses?

Comment: @AlexTerreaux Done.. because I'm such a rep whore :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes without an explicit access modifier (and aren't nested) are implied to be `internal`.

Therefore:

```
class Layout : Form
```

..is internal, whereas:

```
public partial class MainAdminWindow : Layout
```

..is public (because you've explicitly said so). Changing Layout's declaration to this solves the issue:

```
public class Layout : Form
```

Comment: The default access modifier is 'internal': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx